# Check if first radio button w/jQuery

Tags: jquery

If i build a list of items with radiobuttons next to them, how do I check the first one by default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="a" checked>
```

Simply include the checked attribute.

Or through jQuery,

```
$("#groupids:first").prop('checked', 'checked');
```

Answer (score 5):

`$(".radio_identifier:first").prop('checked', 'checked');`

Comment: I know it makes not difference with the current jq, but `prop` is more future proof, and conceptually makes more sense.

Comment: @Andrew you're right, changed to reflect.  santa, could you mark the question (either my answer or Andrews) as accepted to aid future Googlers?